# Yarn offline cache strange behavior

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I'm having trouble setting up my yarn configs to work behind the proxy. In fact, I'm simply supposed to set up the offline cache like it is told in [this tutorial](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/). That's what I do, and it perfectly works on my machine that is connected to internet, even when connection is off.

But when I take the cache, put it on the machine behind the proxy, and set up configs like I did just before on the other computer, it breaks when used.
I get this error message:

```
there should only be one folder in a package cache (got )
```

I've been googling that, and yarn github open (and closed!) issues  for hours, without success. What does that `(got <space>)` means? In the `yarn-error.log` file, no more informations are shown. I double checked my `npm-packages-offline-cache` and there are only `.tgz`s (not tagged as dirs, of course) in it (I did `ll -a` of course).

Did anyone ever hear of it? Or is it a known bug (among many others) of this yarn thing?
Thanks for considering my request.

Answer (score 11):

Not sure about this - I'm researching similar issues.  But this seemed to make this one go away

`yarn cache clean`

Comment: I had the same problem with `got ( <path of my cache dir>)` and running `yarn cache clean` resolved it -- I then ran `yam --offline` and it works. I had this problem after a failed @tfjs install. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was going crazy looking for a dependency I don't even have in my project

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of all `.DS_Store` files from the yarn cache directory, while still keeping your cached packages by running the following command:

```bash
find `yarn cache dir` -name '.DS_Store' -type f -prune -print -exec rm '{}' \;
```